Issue with CreateToolhelp32Snapshot and OpenProcess interaction in Windows 11
I'm encountering a peculiar issue with my C++ application on Windows 11 involving the functions CreateToolhelp32Snapshot and OpenProcess. Here's a brief overview of the problem:
When my code calls GetAllModulesInfoOfPID(Second block), which internally calls CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (First block) to retrieve module information of a process identified by its PID, CreateToolhelp32Snapshot returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE with error code 0x5 (Access Denied). However, if I comment out the call to GetRDataSectionBaseAddress (Last block), the subsequent function GetAllModulesInfoOfPID (which uses CreateToolhelp32Snapshot) executes without errors.
char** GetAllModulesInfoOfPID(DWORD PID, int* numModules) {
    //CreateToolHelp32Snapshot is powerfull
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, PID);
    if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        switch (GetLastError()){
            case 5:
                warn("PID: %-6d, Denied Access", PID);
                break;
            case 299:
                warn("PID: %-6d, Error Memory Management", PID);
                break;
            default:
                warn("PID: %-6d, [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot] failed to get handle, Error: %lx", GetLastError());
                break;
        }
        *numModules = 0;
        return nullptr;
    }
//...

    if (processList) {
        info("Writing in list_MODULES_imports:");
        for (int i = 0; i < numProcesses; i++) {
            int numModules = 0;
            char** moduleNames = GetAllModulesInfoOfPID(processList[i].pid, &numModules);
            if (moduleNames) {
                // If you call get_all_modules_info_of_PID and GetRDataSectionBaseAddress it'll denies access magically
                for (int j = 0; j < numModules; ++j) {
                    fprintf(outputFile, "%s (%d), %s\n", moduleNames[0], processList[i].pid, moduleNames[j]);
                    //get_exported_functions(processList[i].pid, processList[i].processName);
                }
                free_module_names(moduleNames, numModules);
            } else {
                //pass
            }
        }
    } else { return false; }

LPVOID GetRDataSectionBaseAddress(DWORD PID, const char* moduleName) {
    info("[GetRDataSectionBaseAddress] call");
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, PID);
    if (hProcess == NULL) {
        warn("[OpenProcess] failed to get handle to %d. Error: %lx", PID, GetLastError());
        return nullptr;
    }

    HMODULE hModules[1024];
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    if (!EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hModules, sizeof(hModules), &cbNeeded)) {
        warn("[EnumProcessModules] failed to list modules. Error: %lx", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return NULL;
    }

    HMODULE hModule = NULL;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++) {
        char szModuleName[MAX_PATH];
        if (GetModuleBaseNameA(hProcess, hModules[i], szModuleName, sizeof(szModuleName))) {
            if (_stricmp(szModuleName, moduleName) == 0) {
                hModule = hModules[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (hModule == NULL) {
        warn("[GetModuleBaseNameA] failed to get name of module. Error: %lx", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return NULL;
    }

    MODULEINFO moduleInfo;
    if (!GetModuleInformation(hProcess, hModule, &moduleInfo, sizeof(moduleInfo))) {
        warn("[GetModuleInformation] failed to get info about module. Error: %lx", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return NULL;
    }

    BYTE* moduleBase = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll);
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER>(moduleBase);
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS>(moduleBase + dosHeader->e_lfanew);

    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(ntHeaders);
    for (int i = 0; i < ntHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
        if (strncmp(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sectionHeader->Name), ".rdata", IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME) == 0) {
            LPVOID rdataBaseAddress = moduleBase + sectionHeader->VirtualAddress;
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            okay("Got base address of .rdata");
            return rdataBaseAddress;
        }
        sectionHeader++;
    }

    warn("Failed to get .rdata base address");
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return NULL;
}

    if (processList) {
        info("Writing in list_importExport_table:");
        for (int i = 0; i < numProcesses; i++) {
            if (contains_exe(processList[i].processName)){
                //system("pause");
                info("Base Address of .rdata of PID %d: %p", processList[i].pid, GetRDataSectionBaseAddress(processList[i].pid, processList[i].processName));
            } else {
                warn("Something went wrong with %s (%d)", processList[i].processName, processList[i].pid);
            }
        }
    } else { return false; }

    fclose(outputFile);
    okay("Operation Success!");

    return true;

Running on Windows 11, with antivirus disabled for the application folder.
I've experimented with different permissions for OpenProcess (e.g., PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ), but the issue persists.
This behavior occurs consistently, and other similar code using NtOpenProcess does not encounter access issues.
I've ensured that all handles are closed properly and there are no resource leaks.
What could be causing CreateToolhelp32Snapshot to fail with Access Denied only when GetRDataSectionBaseAddress is called? How can I resolve or further diagnose this issue?
I expect CreateToolhelp32Snapshot to successfully retrieve process module information even when GetRDataSectionBaseAddress is called prior to GetAllModulesInfoOfPID.

dosHeader->e_lfanew reads e_lfanew from your process, not the target process.
